# Vuetify error: "Error in beforeCreate hook: "Error: Vuetify is not properly initialized"

Tags: typescript, vue.js, asp.net-core, vuetify.js

I am currently trying to incorporate Vuetify into individual Vue components in a NET Core 3 web project with TypeScript.  My understanding is that Vuetify is meant to be used in SPAs, but I would like to do individual cshtml pages with Vue component tags. The project builds and runs, but I get the error as in the title above.  It points me to [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start), but when I attempt this, I get errors saying that I need a declaration file.  I admit, that I have only minimal experience with TypeScript, but could anyone point in the right direction to what I am missing?  Below are relevant code snippets:

Thanks in advance!

Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home";
}

@section Scripts {
    <script asp-src-include="/js/dist/home*.js"></script>
}

<div id="home">
    <home></home>
</div>
```

home.ts

```
import Vue from "vue";
import home from "./components/home.vue";

let v = new Vue({
    el: "#home",
    components: {
        home
    }
});
```

home.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <v-app>
            <v-container>
                <h1>Home</h1>

                <v-alert type="success">
                    I'm a success alert.
                </v-alert>
            </v-container>
        </v-app>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import { Vue, Component, Prop } from "vue-property-decorator";
    import Vuetify from "vuetify";
    import "vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css";

    Vue.use(Vuetify);

    export default class Home extends Vue {

    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs you should have `new Vuetify()` but I don't see it within your code.

From this docs https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start :

> Create a plugin file for Vuetify, src/plugins/vuetify.js with the
>   below content:

```
/ src/plugins/vuetify.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

const opts = {}

export default new Vuetify(opts)
```

> If using vuetify-loader use the content below:

```
// src/plugins/vuetify.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

const opts = {}

export default new Vuetify(opts)
```

> Navigate to your main entry point where you instantiate your Vue
>   instance and pass the Vuetify object in as an option.

```
// src/main.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import vuetify from '@/plugins/vuetify' // path to vuetify export

new Vue({
  vuetify,
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: Thank you This helped a lot, I had import vuetify directly in my main,js with no standalone plugin and same error as OP